# Inheritance of functions in classes not working Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm in doubt with this program of mine with inheritance, I don't know if I understand the concept wrong or the code is wrong (maybe both), but I really need some help.

The other functions are working, the only problem is when I try to access the Saving class function by the Account (Subclass).

```
class Savings:

    def __init__(self):
        self.money = 0
        self.statement = []

    def apply(self, value):
        self.money += value
        self.statement.append(("Apply", f"${value}"))


class Accounts(Savings):

     def __init__(self, client: Client, bank: Bank):
       super().__init__()
        #other variables 

    def change_money(self):
        print("3 - Apply in Savings")
        choose = int(input("Choose: "))
        elif choose == 3:
             value = float(input("Value to apply: $").replace(",", "."))
             super().apply(value)
             print(super().money)
        else:
            pass
```

And when I try to access the money variable, it says

```
super().money    
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'money'
```

I made a test using only Accounts as Object and the money variable changed,

**Input:**

```
    a = Accounts()
    
    a.change_money()
    a.money
```

**Output**

```
3 - Apply in Savings
Choose: 3
Value to apply: $100

100.0
```

but Accounts and Savings are different classes and I need to access it and change from the Subclass

Please, can anyone help me ?

Comment: I don't see the `super().money` in the first code snippet. Where is it placed?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to put it in code

Comment: You're very close. Reading about scopes and classes/objects in Python can be useful https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: Please post working code that demonstrates the error. Your child class doesn't call the parent init properly and you don't have code that generates the error. Make it easy for us to test solutions!

Comment: @tdelaney The problem is that when I call the function by my Subclass, it's not having any effects. It's not like I have a true error. The problem is in the snippet that I posted

Comment: @Marrows The solution is `self.money` instead of `super().money`.

Comment: Isn't your hierarchy backwards? Savings and Checking are different types of Account. So Account should be the superclass, and Savings and Checking should be subclasses.

Comment: You've got me there, I didn't think about it @Barmar

Comment: Copy and paste your code into a .py file and run it. It doesn't work. You aren't calling init correctly and you have an elif without an if. Sometimes snippettes are the best we can do, but in this case you could easily post a working program demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `self.apply(value)` instead:

```py
class Savings:
    def __init__(self):
        self.money = 0
        self.statement = []

    def apply(self, value):
        self.money += value
        self.statement.append(("Apply", f"${value}"))

class Accounts(Savings):
    def change_money(self):
        value = float(input("Value to apply: $"))
        self.apply(value)
        print(self.money)

a = Accounts()

a.change_money() # input, say, 10
print(a.statement) # [('Apply', '$10.0')]
```

Your object `a` inherits the method `apply` attached to itself, so `a` can call its own method by `self.apply`.

Answer (score -1):

You don’t need to call super as it is a pre defined function and is part of the savings accounts class. Just call self.apply(value)